# Fire looks very low resolution

Tags: materials, blender-internal-render-engine, smoke-simulation, volumetrics

I have asked this question before and no one has helped me. I've been given the wrong answer and when I tried to explain that there was no reply. But anyways what my question is, is that I work in internal and when I create fire (high resolution is checked), parts of it is pixelated and looks very noisy. Here we can see it in Godzilla's mouth area:

[image]

And here it is noticeable in certain areas of the flame:
[image]

Comment: Please don't duplicate your questions. If you are not receiving answers please add more information on the original post. Please read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers

Comment: I did that, still got no answer.

Comment: The reason you are not getting asnwers is because there is not enough information on your posts for people to give you a conclusive answer. Please show images of your settings, modifiers, render settings etc. Make your file available for others to inspect. Help those who can help you. **This is not a guess-exchange**, but a question and answer site. A clear question has a better chance to get a good answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under *Intergration* in the material for the smoke domain, decrease the *Step Size* and possibly also the *Depth Cutoff*. The step size determines how close together the volume calculations are, and decreasing it makes the render more accurate, but also slower. The depth cutoff sets the luminance below which to clamp to zero. Decreasing this also makes the render more accurate and slower.

[image]

This was rendered with the default settings, step size 0.100 and depth cutoff 0.010.

[image]

And this was rendered with values in the screenshot above, step size 0.02 and depth cutoff 0.005.

[image]

And as a side note (for if and when you decide to move to Cycles), in Cycles you change this under *Volume Sampling* in the render panel. The step size does the same as in Internal, but the depth cutoff has been replaced by *Max Steps*. This serves the same purpose, but with a different approach.

[image]

Comment: I used the internal one, and it has very good results. The bad thing, however, is that it took like 3 hours to render. Is there another solution that has a short render time, or one that won't take an hour to render? Thanks!

Comment: Three hours for an animation or a still image? If you're doing an animation, a few hours seems pretty normal to me. How many frames?

Comment: That was for a still image.

Comment: Never mind it renders fine now, don't know what that was. Thanks again!